# Infinite restart of Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

Resently, I've searched the way to restart my Chrome.

And found the way: enter `chrome://restart` in url.

It restarted, but when it was back it restarted again and again.

It seems because I have "Restore previous tabs" option on.

Now my chrome is not working, because the only thing it can do is restart.

How can I get it back to life?
Somehow close the tab with `chrome://restart` or switch off "Restore previous tabs" option?

Comment: Re-installing it would probably work

Comment: I've registered a bug on google about this https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=340130

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have chrome attached to your toolbar you should be able to right click and start in incognito mode.

From there I believe you'll be able to change your settings.